# how can I install the intel composer xe (icc) under open suse 12.3?

Tags: icc, suse

I would like to use the Intel cpp compiler under open SUSE 12.3.
I have downloaded the non-commercial version from here:
http://software.intel.com/non-commercial-software-development,

but when I run install.sh I get an error message saying my OS was not supported.

I also read [this page](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-intel-compilers-on-opensuse), where it is explained how to install the icc under opensuse, but I have no idea which download file they are talking about.

It cant be that hard to install icc under OpenSuse 12.3, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You download link is correct. The latest version now is 2013_sp1.0.080. According to the [relase notes](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/407601/release-notes-c-2013sp1-l-en.pdf), only these linux distributions are officially supported.

- Fedora* 18,19
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux* 5, 6
- SUSE LINUX Enterprise Server* 10, 11 SP2
- Ubuntu* 12.04 LTS, 13.04
- Debian* 6.0, 7.0

However the OS support is often a **optional pre-request**. You should be able to continue the following installation by choosing to ignore it.

On the other hand, the second link you provided seems published on 2011. You could go to Intel forum for updates.